# Закрытие Word с сохранением

Tags: c#, ms-word

Задача: при запуске приложения найти все открытые документы Word и закрыть их с сохранением изменений не выводя диалог о подтверждении сохранения.

Как через процессы их все убить понятно, а вот как все сохранить то что было открыто до запуска самого приложения не понятно...

Comment: Насчёт макроса не думали?

Comment: Если макрос - то если я правильно понимаю это знание visual basic... А этих знаний нет(((

Comment: Ну, на уровне простого макроса, думаю, _знания_ и не понадобятся, язык всё же очень простой.

Comment: Через [IRunningObjectTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695276(v=vs.85).aspx) можно добраться до COM-интерфейса приложения, там есть метод сохранения документа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   try
        {
            var myApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as Word.Application;
            myApp.Documents.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges);
            myApp.Application.Quit();
        }
        catch { };

        Application.Exit();
```

Вот что мне требовалось.

Comment: ну так это тоже самое, что в ответе ниже (включая комментарий).

Answer (score 3):

Можно используя `Office.Interop`.

```
var myApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as Word.Application;
myApp.Save();
```

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655210/attach-to-existing-excel-instance) похожий вопрос про `Exel`.

Comment: Так выводит запрос на подтверждение сохранения, нужно чтобы не спрашивал, а сразу сохранял и закрывал все доки...

Comment: @Александр А там нету перегрузок этого метода? Должна быть с параметром `NoPrompt`, задаете `true`. Или должно сработать:  `myApp.ActiveDocument.Close(savechanges:=True)`
 `myApp.Quit`